# C# Windows Forms. Login form

Tags: c#

I have a login form, and I need something more.

I need my program to close, if 3 incorrect attempts are made.

Here is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "hvelreki")
        MessageBox.Show("Ласкаво просимо!");
    if (textBox2.Text == "sigurros")
        MessageBox.Show("Ласкаво просимо");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("***, gg");
}
```

How can I make it exit after the third incorrect attempt?

Answer (score 4):

first you should declare a static variable to count the login attempts like this:

`static int loginAttemps = 0;`

after that, where you check for credentials you should add 1 to it and check the credentials if it's correct then proceed if it's not check the `loginAttempts` if it's over `close()`, like this :

```
    private static int loginAttempts = 0;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (textBox1.Text == "hvelreki")
          MessageBox.Show("Ласкаво просимо!");
       if (textBox2.Text == "sigurros")
          MessageBox.Show("Ласкаво просимо");
       else{
          loginAttemps++;
          if(loginAttempts >= 3)
              Application.exit();
       }


}
```

Hope this help...

Comment: friend, i`m new in C#.
pls can you write it in your windows form and screen? if you can of course(

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH***
GOD BLESS YOU)

Comment: It may be an idea to reset the loginAttempts back to 0 on a successful login attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Exit()` to quit your forms app. To count how many attempts a user tried to login use a member variable and increment it when the login button is clicked:

```
private int _loginAttempts;
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 _loginAttempts++;
// Your code here
}
```

Comment: i know, but i need to do it after 3 uncorrect attempts. how to do it?

Comment: Use a member variable